# which data type to store UTC offsets in MySQL

Tags: mysql, timezone

I have a MySQL table of timezones in which I am storing and sorting UTC offsets.  UTC offsets have values like +03:00, -10:00, +00:00, +05:30 and so on.  The complete list can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

What data type should I use to store this UTC offset column?  I am currently using the `time` datatype which appends an additional ":00" seconds to each UTC offset.  I also tried using `varchar`, which is fine, but may not make sense semantically for other DB admins.

**Update**

I am also considering using `int` with each offset represented as a number of seconds.  This would make the column very easy to sort.

Comment: Depending on what you're doing, it's possible that you're much better off not going down this path. The bottom line is offsets change during the year or when governments feel like it. Always store single points in time as UTC timestamps. Convert to datetimes in the user's local timezone on the fly.

Comment: +1 to bcmcfc's comment.  See also "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).  However, if you are storing a local date/time in one field, and an offset in another, to form a "datetimeoffset" for a single point in time, then akuzminsky's answer is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the perfect fit for TIME data type.

> TIME
>
> A time. The range is '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59'. MySQL displays TIME values in 'HH:MM:SS' format, but permits assignment of values to TIME columns using either strings or numbers.